# A button in my react app is not visible in browsers on iphone

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, mern

I'm new to React and as a hobby I developed a MERN stack website and deployed to heroku. It works fine on my laptop and android phones; But when I tried it on iphone 6 and iphone 7 phones, I noticed that one of the submit buttons did not appear. (Material-UI button) I think if there was an error in the code, it would not work properly anywhere. Why could such a problem occur on iPhone? Can you help me please? For example the codes of my post add page

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import {
  generalContext,
  authContext,
} from "../../../../../WRAPPERS/Context/myContext";
import Editor from "../../../../editor/Editor";
import Input from "../../../../formelements/Input";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/styles/makeStyles";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import useHttpClient from "../../../../../hooks/useHttpClient";
import { useForm } from "../../../../../hooks/useForm";
import ImageUpload from "../../../../formelements/imageUpload/imageUpload";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Spinner from "../../../../spinner/Spinner";

const InsertBlog = () => {
  const { isLoading, error, open, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
  const general = useContext(generalContext);
  const auth = useContext(authContext);
  const history = useHistory();
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

  const [select, setselect] = useState();

  const [newPost, setNewPost] = useState({
    title: "",
    content: "",
  });

  const [formState, inputHandler, setFormData] = useForm(
    {
      image: {
        value: "",
        isValid: false,
      },
    },
    false
  );

  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    form: {
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      paddingBottom: ".5rem",
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      justifyContent: "space-between",
      textAlign: "center",
      overflowX: "hidden",
    },
    label: {
      textDecoration: "underline",
      margin: ".3rem auto .2rem auto",
      fontSize: "1rem",
    },
    formControl: {
      margin: "1rem",
      minWidth: 120,
    },
  });

  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCategories = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await sendRequest(
          process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + "/blog/categories"
        );
        console.log(res.categories);
        setCategories(res.categories);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    fetchCategories();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {isLoading && <Spinner />}

      <form
        className={classes.form}
        onSubmit={async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          try {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("title", newPost.title);
            formData.append("content", newPost.content);
            formData.append("image", formState.inputs.image.value);
            formData.append("kullanici", auth.userId);
            formData.append("username", auth.name);
            formData.append("category", select);
            const responseData = await sendRequest(
              process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + `/blog`,
              "POST",
              formData
            );
            setNewPost({ title: "", content: "" });
            history.push(
              `/Blog/postId/${responseData.blog._id}/Başlık/${responseData.blog.title}`
            );
          } catch (err) {}
        }}
      >
        <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-age-native-simple">
            Lütfen Bir Kategori Seçin
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            required
            native
            value={select}
            onChange={(e) => setselect(e.target.value)}
            label="Lütfen Bir Kategori Seçin"
            inputProps={{
              name: "Lütfen Bir Kategori Seçin",
              id: "outlined-age-native-simple",
            }}
          >
            <option aria-label="None" value="" />
            {!isLoading &&
              categories.length > 0 &&
              categories.map((category) => (
                <option key={category._id} value={category._id}>
                  {category.label}
                </option>
              ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <Input
          required
          bg="white"
          label="Post Başlığı"
          style={{ marginTop: ".1rem", flex: 1 }}
          inputStyle={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }}
          value={newPost.title}
          onChange={(e) => setNewPost({ ...newPost, title: e.target.value })}
        />
        <Editor
          type="blog"
          style={{ flex: 15 }}
          value={newPost.content}
          onChange={(e, editor) => {
            const data = editor.getData();
            setNewPost({ ...newPost, content: data });
          }}
        />
        <ImageUpload
          id="image"
          onInput={inputHandler}
          center
          errorText="Lütfen Geçerli Bir Resim Yükleyiniz"
        />
        <Button
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          variant="contained"
          size="medium"
          color="primary"
          fullWidth
          type="submit"
        >
          Gönder
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default InsertBlog;
```

[The Gönder(submit) button normally looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tUWS.png)

[The button not showing up on iphone 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCNCf.jpg)

Comment: There are a ton of potential causes and it's hard to narrow down! When asking Stackoverflow questions, it helps to provide context. For example, you could provide sample code, screenshots of how it looks on each platform, and more.

Comment: Okay. I'm gonna update now.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is in the styles `flex`

**Could be resolved in three ways:**

(1)`flex: 1 1;`

(2)`-webkit-flex: 1 1 100%;`

(3)

```
    form: {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      flexDirection: column;
      paddingBottom: .5rem;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      justifyContent: space-between;
      textAlign: center;
      overflowX: hidden;
   }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.. Thanks for your help